# Basic SSO on .NET API

Tags: .net, azure, single-sign-on

I'm trying to build a basic SSO authentication using Visual Studio 2017 right now. Assuming I am using a .net application I already got the SSO target that I need (refer to this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/)

Now I am trying to create an SSO using the VS MVC Api with authentication Wizard using Azure portal.

[image]

After running this project, by default it created an app on my Azure portal. Now I would want to hit the "api/test" and the expected result is it will redirect me to the sign on page. but right now it does not. Am I missing something?

I look at the webconfig and all the default details are already there that I needed to run the same one on the .net application.

Comment: An API usually does not redirect to login. Since the users of an API are not users right? That's why APIs usually use token authentication, where the apps calling the API acquire a token and then attach that to requests. In the case of AAD, you should use JwtBearer authentication.

Comment: hi @juunas, I saw an approach that states like the one you said. It says I have an application which authenticate the user, the other application registered as the API layer. Then I will enable the user layer to access the API layer. So what happens is it become an "Application Identity authentication"

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity/

Is this the right approach on my case?

Comment: Depends on if you want your API to be aware of the signed-in user or not. Using an app identity or client credentials means the token will only contain info about the app, no user info. But, if you use delegated access, like authorization code flow in the front-end, the token will contain user info as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look for that approach. If I may ask, do you have a link for that one?

Comment: There are code samples for v1 endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code and v2 endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code. Use v2 if you can. There's also tutorials + protocol references on there.